# NOTEPAD ++ find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I iam trying to convert my data from this form e.x `12hju 1002` to `,("1002")` and `,("12hju")`. 
How can i suround my data with this `,("")` between `""` is my data .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Are there always two "words" separated by a comma. Do you really want to invert the 2? Please add some sample cases and expected result.

Comment: no the comma is not exist my fault

Comment: Ok, no comma. What about other question? do you want to have the result on one line, 2 lines, ..?

Comment: this is going for a database entry so thats why i need my data to have the syntax ...  so lines iits ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+),(\S+)`
- Replace with: `\("$2"\),\("$1"\)`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : start of string
  (\S)          : group 1, 1 or more non space
  \s            : a space
  (\S)          : group 2, 1 or more non space
```

Note: with Npp, the parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the `,` with `"),("` and then add the `("` in the beginning and `")` at the end manually.

Answer (score 0):

A regex as `([\d\w]+),([\d]+)` and replace with `,\("\2"\),\("\1"\)` will do exactly what you want for your single data entry.

You'll likely need to tune the regex to the entire set.